# How do we implement SQL Server IF EXISTS (SELECT) in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, upsert

We would like to convert the following SQL Server statement:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT OptionValue
          FROM Options
          WHERE OptionCatagory = 'General' AND
                OptionName = 'HVRCustomPortNumber')
   UPDATE Option
   SET OptionValue = @custportnum 
   WHERE OptionCatagory = 'General' AND 
         OptionName ='HVRCustomPortNumber' 
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Options (OptionCatagory, OptionName, OptionValue)
   Values
   ('General', 'HVRCustomPortNumber, @custportnum);
```

to MySQL version 5.6 so that it runs correctly using C# MySQL Connector .NET on Ubuntu Linux 15.10.

I tried googling how to do this and could not find any "hits" that passed the MySQL GUI Query Analyzer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Options` has a unique key on `(OptionCatagory, OptionName)`, you can use a fake `UPSERT`/`MERGE`. More details can be found on MySQL's documentation:
[**`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`** syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
INSERT INTO Options
(OptionCatagory, OptionName, OptionValue)
VALUES( 'General', 'HVRCustomPortNumber', @custportnum)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
OptionValue = @custportnum;
```

The last part can also be written:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
OptionValue = VALUES( OptionValue );
```